# HTML label color in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a very general web page where I display information. I have this code in my .cshtml:

```
<div style="text-align: left">
    Test&nbsp;&nbsp;<p style="color: #1e83ca;"> @Html.Label(Model.MemberName) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    Beruf&nbsp;&nbsp;@Html.Label(Model.ProfessionName)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Datum&nbsp;&nbsp;@Html.Label(Model.TestTakenDate.ToString()) 
</div>
```

I want differentiate the text that I display reading from the database from what is the fixed text. I am using the helper Label and there is no difference. I get all black text. How do I make only what is in the @Html.label in different  color? OR what else can I use to make them look different.

Comment: I tried to do it with <p> tag but that writes on the next line so I dont want that. All the info has to be on one line.

Comment: Look at html attributes, that is right place to define them. Also it is recommended to put html attribute classes in a css document.

Comment: I don't want it for the whole <div> section but only for the text specifies in the label. What attribute can I use for the @html.Label ??

Comment: Use <span> for the rest of the text. For non-formatted section.

Comment: I used span and it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: can you vote for <span>, as it worked for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, try to use `<span>`. That will work !

Answer (score 6):

I just did the following and it worked for me:

```
@Html.Label("This is a label", new { style = "color:#ff0000"})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Html.Label(Model.ProfessionName, new {@class = "mylabel" })
```

in css

```
.mylabel
{
   color: green;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't take in the second parameter as you suggested.How do I specify my style to it?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your @Html.Label classes.

so in your css :

```
.database { color: #1e83ca; }
```

and in your cshtml

```
@Html.Label(Model.MemberName, new { @class = "database"} )
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not taking in the second parameter as class.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify the HTML attributes by supplying an additional parameter to the Label HTMLHelper?

Something like:

```
<%= Html.Label("This is a label", new { style : "color:#FF0000;" } ) %>
```

Comment: It is not taking in second parameter as style. What else?